# android adt 17 - add jar to project - jar in dexedlibs/ only contains a manifest

Tags: android, jar, project, adt

i am using a 3 day old download of adt 17 on win 7 x64 with java 1.7.

adding a jar to my new sample project (by copying it to libs/) compiles fine, but throws at runtime because the classes in the jar are not in the corresponding jar in dexedlibs/ - that jar only contains a manifest.

related links: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 and http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects.

doing some of the export and order stuff suggested in the links does not help.

how does one know how to add a jar to an android project these days?

edit: thanks to max: the jar was made using java 1.7, specifying 1.6 stopped the throwing, but i still get some missing methods for some reason (these are not called, but they are referenced).

```
12-20 23:02:13.689: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 
12-20 23:02:13.689: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:13.689: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:13.949: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:13.949: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:14.829: I/dalvikvm(27907): Could not find method com.tayek.utilities.Utilities.store, referenced from method com.tayek.qanda.Model.toPropertiesFile
12-20 23:02:14.829: W/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3399: Lcom/tayek/utilities/Utilities;.store (Ljava/io/File;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
12-20 23:02:14.829: D/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
12-20 23:02:14.849: I/dalvikvm(27907): Could not find method com.tayek.utilities.Utilities.store, referenced from method com.tayek.qanda.Model.toPropertiesFile
12-20 23:02:14.849: W/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3399: Lcom/tayek/utilities/Utilities;.store (Ljava/io/File;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
12-20 23:02:14.849: D/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
12-20 23:02:14.849: I/dalvikvm(27907): Could not find method com.tayek.utilities.Utilities.store, referenced from method com.tayek.qanda.Model.toPropertiesFile
12-20 23:02:14.849: W/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3400: Lcom/tayek/utilities/Utilities;.store (Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
12-20 23:02:14.849: D/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
12-20 23:02:14.849: I/dalvikvm(27907): Could not find method com.tayek.utilities.Utilities.store, referenced from method com.tayek.qanda.Model.toPropertiesFile
12-20 23:02:14.849: W/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3400: Lcom/tayek/utilities/Utilities;.store (Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
12-20 23:02:14.849: D/dalvikvm(27907): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
12-20 23:02:14.929: I/System.out(27907): Hospital Mortality Risk
12-20 23:02:14.969: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:14.969: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:14.969: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:14.989: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.029: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.029: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.040: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.160: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.160: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.160: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.169: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.169: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.169: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.189: D/gralloc_goldfish(27907): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-20 23:02:15.258: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 23:02:15.299: W/Trace(27907): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

update: importing a jar with trivial classes works fine.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you find a solution? Cheers

Comment: no, but a friend made this work on his similar system by explicitly adding the jar and fooling with the export and order. but that does not seem to work for me :(

Comment: Are you using Java 7? I fixed the issue by changing the Java library setting for the Java project to jre1.6 instead of 1.7. You could always try it :)

Comment: i am using java 7, but compiler compliance level is set to 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 you can try changing the runtime environment for the Java library project:

1. Right click and the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
2. Choose JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7] and click edit
3. Change execution environment to JavaSE-1.6 (jre7)

This worked for me using ADT 21.

Comment: i don't see any choice for JRE System Library under project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

Comment: @RayTayek Ah, you need to compile and export the actual jar with those settings. If the library is not compiled and exported by you, then I don't think this answer applies. Sorry.

Comment: oh, i was using gradle to build the jar.

Comment: i changed the gradle build file to do 1.6. this got rid of the throwing. still complains about missing methods though

Comment: @RayTayek Missing methods? What complains about missing methods, and in which way? Update your question with more info, and we might solve that as well :)